# How can I put packed parameter types into a tuple?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

```
template<typename... Args, typename Action>
    void execute(const Action& _action) {
       using all_components = std::tuple<Args...>;
       auto tuple = std::tie();
       for (int s = 0; s < all_components.size(); s++) {                     
          tuple = std::tuple_cat(tuple, *reinterpret_cast<get<s>(all_components)*>(data[s]);
        }
       std::apply(_action, tuple);
    }
```

I want to access the Parameter types, so I can cast my data that is saved in `vector<char>` type. In the type the function action needs it to have. But I'm not sure if how to access them. This was my idea, but it doesn't work, as the get function returns error: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected 'type specifier', I get what the error means, no explanation needed, but I need an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

1. `all_components` is a type, it does not have `size()` method. You can use `sizeof...(Args)` to obtain the length of the pack.
2. `std::get` requires a tuple object. Since it is a cast, thus unevaluated context, you can use `std::declval<all_components>()` to obtain the tuple.
3. Because `std::get` returns a value, you have to convert it to a type for it to be casted to.

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template<typename... Args, typename Action>
void execute(const Action& _action) {
    using all_components = std::tuple<Args...>;
    auto tuple = std::tie();
    for (int s = 0; s < sizeof...(Args); s++) {                     
        tuple = std::tuple_cat(tuple, *reinterpret_cast<decltype(std::get<s>(std::declval<all_components>()))*>(data[s]);
    }
    std::apply(_action, tuple);
}
```

But

- you are still missing `data`.
- Because `s` is used in a template, it has to be constexpr, so the ordinary loop won't compile.
- Is `sizeof` of every `Arg` 1? If not, the deserialization is wrong.

My wild guess is that the data is tightly packed inside the vector. In that case you need something like this:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template<typename...Args>
constexpr auto data_indices(){
    std::array is{std::size_t(0), sizeof(Args)...};
    for(std::size_t i=1;i<is.size();++i){
        is[i]+=is[i-1];
    }
    return is;
}

template<typename...Args,std::size_t...Is>
auto get_tuple(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const char* data){
    auto indices = data_indices<Args...>();
    return std::tuple{*reinterpret_cast<const Args*>(data+indices[Is])...};
}

template<typename... Args, typename Action>
void execute(const Action& _action, const char* data) {
    std::apply(_action, get_tuple<Args...>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{},data));
}

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x, double y){
    std::cout<<x<<' '<<y<<'\n';
}
int main(){
    
    std::array<char,sizeof(int)+sizeof(double)> arr;
    int x = 12;
    double y = 24.0;
    std::memcpy(arr.data(),&x,sizeof(x));
    std::memcpy(arr.data()+sizeof(x), &y,sizeof(y));

    execute<int,double>(foo,arr.data());
}
```

Unless you are using placement `new` to put the elements into the array, you have to explicitly copy them to the tuple, otherwise you are breaking the strict aliasing rule. So:

```cpp
template<typename...Args,std::size_t...Is>
auto get_tuple(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const char* data){
    auto indices = data_indices<Args...>();
    std::tuple<Args...> tuple;

    (std::memcpy(&std::get<Is>(tuple), data+indices[Is], sizeof(Args)), ...);
    return tuple;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Maybe i should explicitly say that this was a bit pseudoish code, as i didn't want to post too much source code, my real question is, how to acces the ...Args and then use them in the reinterpret cast, is the tuple method the way to go, or can i do it better by recursion, im a bit stuck there.

Comment: @MaximilianWolter I do not know what exactly you want now. What do you mean by access the Args? Like get n-th element? That can be done by some helper methods, but you could write your code around pack expansion as I did. Is my solution not what you wanted ? (That would be fine). The main problem with your source code is that the loop would have to be constexpr since `s` is used as a template parameter. Can you precisely specify what is the role of `data` w.r.t Args?